# relationship between controller interrupt no and interrupt no in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling

I am developing our own CAN kernel module in i.mx6 processor. Now we want to write ISR for CAN TX and RX. We are able to write ISR, but my question is for register my ISR using **request_irq** function, what is the irq no i have to give. What is the relation between interrupt no specified in controller datasheet and irq no in the above function.

Thanks in advance,
NSN

Comment: You have to supply *Linux* IRQ number. Each architecture has its own rules how to convert  *hardware* IRQ to *Linux* one. It among other things depends on type of the bus and resource provider (DT, ACPI, legacy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are we talking about on-chip FlexCAN or is this an externally connected CAN controller like MCP2515? There is already a FlexCAN driver available in the kernel. For on-chip peripherals the IRQ's are already defined in the Technical Reference Manual. For iMX6D/Q have a look at Chapter 3 Interrupts and DMA events. The interrupts are specified in device tree and retrieved using request_irq. For a CAN controller, let's say connected over SPI, a GPIO can be used as interrupt and the interrupt would be specified in device tree using "interrupt-parents" and "interrupts" property.

For the exact relation, let's consider an example. The CAN1 node is [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl.dtsi#n555) with the "interrupts" property having a number of 110. If you look at Section 3 of TRM, FlexCAN1 is suppose to have an IRQ number of 142. Since the ARM Cortex A9 domain numbers start from 32, just subtract this from 142 to get the number of 110.

Edit: Seems I was not fully clear and talked from the device tree POV. The IRQ number for request_irq should have come from a call to platform_get_irq which returns Linux IRQ numbers. Also see [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/IRQ-domain.txt).

Comment: Read my comment above.

Comment: I modified it based on your input

Comment: Thank for your reply. In our dts file the IRQ no is 110. We get the irq no we have used below piece of code whether our approach is correct or not we dont know. please verify and reply.                                                                                      struct device_node * np = NULL;

   np = of_find_node_by_name(NULL,"flexcan");


    if (np == NULL)
    {

       printk("Error node not found\n");

    }

    else
    {
   virq = irq_of_parse_and_map(np,0);

       dev->irqno = virq; 

       printk("CAN: Can 0 irq no: %d\n",virq);
  }

Comment: There is already a driver for FlexCAN. Why are you writing your flexcan driver?

Comment: We have our own filters to be configured in CAN modules. That why we want to go for our own driver. Sorry for delay reply as i am out of station

Comment: Not sure if you are talking about the same filters that I am thinking of. Did you have a look or are aware of can_filters? See Section 4.1 in [networking/can.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt). For getting IRQ, please see existing usage of platform_get_irq or request_irq like [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/can/flexcan.c#n1230)